# Can food which are proven to increase sexual libido be considered "Tamasica"?

Tags: food, science, sex, ayurveda

One of *tamasic* food is food that has ''sedative effect on the body''. Now this can mean libido boosting food can be said to be *Tamasic*. *Tamasic* food such as onions, garlic and meat are indeed libido boosting.
Now in ancient India, dark chocolates and fruits such as pomegranates & watermelon were not available and these food are scientifically proven to be libido boosting. So can these foods be considered to be *tamasic*?

Comment: Pomogranate is known as Dadimi and it was available in ancient times refer Markandeya Purana devi mahatmyam. Watermelon is also native to india since its brother Winter melon is/was widely available and mentioned in scriptures (known as kushmand in sanskrit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"One of tamasic food is food that has ''sedative effect on the body''. Now this can mean libido boosting food can be said to be Tamasic ... So can these food be considered to be tamasic?"*

**No**. The food which "boosts" something (i.e. libido) cannot have "sedating" or dullness effect. The ***tAmasika*** foods are those which are **stale & smelly**. Onion, garlic, meat may not be necessarily containing more *tamas*.

A *sAtvika/rAjasika* food kept too long for rotting, would develop *tamas* quality. BTW certain foods (like fruits, [dhebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhebra)) would not possess much *tamas* quality even if kept for few days. Hence one needs to be judicious among the types of the foods.

Following are the food likings for the people with nature of *sattva, rajas & tamas*:

> BG 17.8 - Foods that augment life, firmness of mind, strength, health, happiness and delight, and which are succulent, oleaginous, substantial and agreeable, are dear to one endowed with *sattva*.
>   BG 17.9 - Foods that are bitter, sour, salty, very hot, pungent, dry and burning, and which production pain, sorrow and disease, are dear to one having *rajas*.
>   BG 17.10 - Food which is not properly cooked, lacking in essence, **putrid and stale**, and even leftover and that which is unfit for sacrifice, is dear to one possessed of ***tamas***.

All the foods have these 3 modes, in more or less or equal amounts.

---

*Libido* (desire for sex) is one of the many desires. **The food which boosts the desires are *RAjasika***. Because the lust/*desires* (*kAma*) is born out of the *Rajas*.

> BG 3.37 - The blessed lord said: **This desire(lust), this anger, born out of *Rajas*(passion)** -- are great devourers(consumers), great sinners; Know that to be enemy here.

Hence if the foods such as certain chocolates, pickles, spices, chilli etc. (or certain fruits) which may increase libido -- are *RAjasika*.

The rule of thumb:

- *SAtvika* food: Can be eaten regularly to keep the body fit & working; Hence these foods are *DhArmika*; i.e. consumable daily without any side effects & satisfying; e.g. All Indian home cooked items which are fresh & easily digestible
- *RAjasika* food: Strong on taste buds, but bad on stomach; Any artificially tasty food are usually bad for health -- too sweet/spicy/salty/bitter/hot/cold,... e.g. items usually available in food joints & are consumed for fun
- *TAmasika* food: Dull in all aspects; It has neither taste nor freshness nor health; It's consumed in the state of ignorance; e.g. liquor (notebook example), uncooked meat, packaged/refrigerated items; They bring lethargy