# Food Being Considered Aamish

Tags: food, non-vegetarian

Why are onions and garlic considered aamish (non-veg) among Hindus? Is there a scientific / religious reason for it?

Comment: Actually they are not considered as non veg. But it is discouraged because it haram earth warms on the ground. It is more over a jain(jainism) practice, not a hindu.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/97/17833, Hopefully this might answer your question.

Comment: Since several of your questions might have been closed in here recently @user758469, don't be discouraged to ask questions **BUT**, I'd suggest you to please visit this [FAQ INDEX on the HSE META](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) , please go through it properly and then maybe get started in here for an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: You can see the last part of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23349/4732) answer.

Comment: And this one: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22027/4732

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversations between a devotee and Bhagavan Ramana Maharshi from the book *Letters from Sri Ramanasramam*

> Devotee: There is a saying amongst us that the good which garlic can
> do, even a mother cannot do. That verse expresses the same sentiment.”
>
> Bhagavan: “Such a saying is prevalent in this part of the country
> also. People say it is very good for health. Really it is so. It
> removes rheumatism and gives strength to the body. For children it
> acts like amrit (nectar). Garlic is also known as amrit.”
>
> Devotee: “How did it get that name?”
>
> Bhagavan: “There is a curious story about it. As is well known, when
> gods (devas) and demons (rakshasas) churned the ocean, amrit came out
> of it. When the rakshasas were running away with the vessel containing
> amrit, devas appealed to Vishnu. Vishnu came on the scene in the shape
> of Mohini (Enchantress), and offered to resolve their quarrel by
> serving amrit to them all. They agreed. While serving it to the gods
> first, it appeared that there might not be enough to go round for the
> demons and so one of the latter got into the line of the gods
> unobserved by Mohini and was swallowing the amrit, when the Sun and
> the Moon noticed it and gave her the hint. She threw the ladle, with
> which the amrit was being served, at the demon. The ladle became the
> Chakra (an invincible lethal weapon of Vishnu) and cut off his head,
> but as amrit had already gone down his throat, the head became a graha
> (planet) and has since been taking vengeance on the Sun and the Moon
> at the time of an eclipse. That is the story. Now, when the head of
> the demon was severed, the trunk fell down and, in the process, a few
> drops of amrit also fell on the ground, and it is said that those
> drops became the garlic plant. That is why it is said that garlic has
> some of the properties of amrit. It is very good for the body. But
> since it also has the touch of the demon, it has tamasic qualities
> too, which affect the mind, if eaten. Hence it is forbidden for
> sadhakas.”
>
> Devotee: “Are not horseradish (mullangi) and drumsticks also forbidden
> for sadhakas?”
>
> Bhagavan: “Yes. Watermelon, horseradish, drumsticks, onions and other
> similar vegetables are forbidden. The mind will be clear and pure
> depending on the sort of food one eats, sattvic or otherwise.