# What type of foods we must not eat during Amavasya tharpanam?

Tags: belief, rituals, food, shraddha, amavasya

I've noticed that there are certain foods that we must not eat during Amavasya days.

I've been told that foods like onion and garlic and certain other foods should be avoided.

But some people tell different reasons and others tell different reasons.

People tell like:

- We must not eat onion and other certain items on that day because they induce sexual feelings.
- We must not eat onion and those other items because they are grown underground. So, we must not eat foods that are grown under the ground.
- We must not eat outside food at all.

**My questions:**

1. Can someone tell me the actual reason on why those foods are avoided on Ammavasya days and which other days it should be avoided?
2. Suppose my father performs Ammavasya Tharpanam, can I eat outside food?

Comment: any vedic ritual must have a component of tapasya (penance) for it to bear fruit. Imagine it is your friend's birthday and you want to get him a card. You go to store, buy it, and then give it to him as is, without signing a personal message, or even your name. Will he like it ? Even though you spent money, the personal touch is required for him to appreciate you, right ? Same with rituals. You can do rituals mechanically, but if you don't follow brahmacharya (no sex) & ahara niyam (no prohibited foods) on that day, it doesn't yield results.

Comment: Sure, thank you for the answer. I request you to provide more information on what are the foods that need to be avoid and for what reasons those foods are avoided? Could you please write an answer? And also the reasons to avoid the act of intercourse? Just asking to understand.

Comment: I literally just mentioned the reason to avoid intercourse - it is a penance. foods to be avoided at all times (irrespective of amavasya) - meat, alcohol, eating at hotels, onion, garlic, mushroom, drumstick, beetroot. since you're just starting out, this list is enough. there are many more which you can attempt after you spiritually don't feel compulsion when avoiding i.e. you WANT to avoid rather than HAVE to avoid.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, could you please tell me why certain foods like onion, garlic, mushroom, drumstick are avoided while other vegetables are avoided? Just wanted to understand the reason.

Comment: you already mentioned the reasons - they are aphrodisiacs (stimulate sexual thoughts). they also grow underground. and there is a puranic reason too - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22010/how-are-onions-and-garlic-to-be-considered-as-non-vegetarian-food/22024#22024

Comment: Thank you. Got the aphrodisiac part. But could you tell me why you mentioned, "They also grow underground" ? Is it that we should not eat foods that grow underground? Is there any specific reason or puranic stories in this regard?